# How to use Smartsheet API to obtain data from Quickbooks Desktop

Tags: quickbooks, smartsheet-api

We would like to pull data from Quickbooks Desktop into Smartsheet. Eventually, we would like to push data the opposite way.

I've researched Smartsheet API and SDK and also Quickbooks Web Connector and QB SDK. I just can't figure out how to make them "talk".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [Getting Started](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#getting-started) section of the Smartsheet API docs. That will give you the basics of interacting with the Smartsheet API.
It looks like Intuit, who make QuickBooks, have something similar on their developer page [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/get-started).
From there you will need to look into setting up a development environment in the programming language you will be using. Then once you have that you can start writing the code using both of the SDKs to interact with either service.
If you aren't looking to write code you could look into a service like Zapier that allows you to build integrations without code.
Zapier can connect to both [Smartsheet](https://zapier.com/apps/smartsheet/integrations) and [QuickBooks](https://zapier.com/apps/quickbooks/integrations).